# pycurl resuming after exception

Tags: python, pycurl

I've created a webservice with [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) and using this as JSON interface. The routine is gathering information as checking URL's for validity and http_code.

```
def get_statuscode(url):
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://"+url)
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
    c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.HEADER, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.NOBODY, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.FAILONERROR, 1)
    #c.setopt(pycurl.E_)
    try:
        c.perform()
    except pycurl.error:
        print "MUH"
        return None
        pass
    temp = c.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
    c.close()
    return temp
```

How can I resume operation after the function is given a truly wrong url:
such as `google.local`
My traceback looks like this and stops execution:

```
In[46]: misc.get_statuscode("google.local")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH\Python\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-46-c47028d49dc0>", line 1, in <module>
    misc.get_statuscode("google.local")
  File "PATH\ops\misc.py", line 12, in get_statuscode
    c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
error: (6, "Couldn't resolve host 'google.local'")
```

Even tried with a `socket.gethostbyname_ex()` but the same result.

```
>>> socket.gethostbyname_ex("google.local")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is wayy old but I believe the answer is for this

```
c.setopt(pycurl.FAILONERROR, 1)
```

to be changed to:

```
c.setopt(pycurl.FAILONERROR, 0)
```

I tested this using your code and this was just a small overlook.

The problem is that it was instructed to bail on errors when this was set to one.

More info on `FAILONERROR` I found here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man3/tclcurl.3.html#contenttoc7

> From Docs:
>
> failonerror
>                 A  1  parameter tells the extension to fail silently if the HTTP
>                 code returned is equal or larger than 400.  The  default  action
>                 would be to return the page normally, ignoring that code.
>
> This  method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where non-
>                 successful response codes will  slip  through,  especially  when
>                 authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).
>
> You  might  get  some amounts of headers transferred before this
>                 situation  is  detected,  like  for  when  a  "100-continue"  is
>                 received  as  a  response  to  a  POST/PUT  and  a 401 or 407 is
>                 received immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You have `return None` in you except that is exiting your function, the pass can be dropped as well. replacing `except pycurl.error:` with `except:` will catch any error.

```
def get_statuscode(url):
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://"+url)
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
    c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.HEADER, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.NOBODY, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.FAILONERROR, 1)
    #c.setopt(pycurl.E_)
    try:
        c.perform()
    except:
        print "MUH"
    temp = c.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
    c.close()
    return temp
```

Comment: Tried this as well. Still same error. It stops the execution. But the `return None` is catchable, this shouldn't be dropped.
EDIT: The `return None` is correct. The problem is, that the execution is stopping before reaching that statement.

Comment: Catching *any* exceptions is of course a bad idea in general. Since there's only one statement in the try block, it's fine.